# Tricky probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, poisson-distribution

The **exact** problem statement: A car trader usually sells 70% of cars during the last four months of the year and 50% of cars during other months. The car trades are independent and identically distributed. What is the probability that the trader will sell 6 out of 12 cars in August or 2 out of 10 in September (round the answer to the nearest hundredth, i.e. second digit after decimal point)?

My attempt: The distribution of cars sold in a fixed period of time follows the Poisson distribution since the trades are iid.

In the month of August, $E[\text{no. of cars sold in Aug}] = 50\% \times 12=6$ because we started with $12$ cars and are expected to sell half of them. Thus, $$p(k)=\frac{6^ke^{-6}}{k!} ~~~\text{so} ~~~p(6)=\frac{6^6e^{-6}}{6!}\approx 16\%.$$

Similarly, $E[\text{no. of cars sold in Sep}] = 70\% \times 10=7$. So, $$p(k)=\frac{7^ke^{-7}}{k!} ~~~\text{so} ~~~p(2)=\frac{7^2e^{-7}}{2!}\approx 2\%.$$

Thus the desired answer is $\approx 18\%$, but this isn't any of the given choices (the largest probability in the choices is 12%).
We could use Binomial distribution because the numbers are small but still the answer would be 22%. Tell me where I'm going wrong.

EDIT: Choices are: 12%, 6%, 1%, 0%.

Comment: I don't understand what "identically distributed" means in this context.  We know that the number of car sales per month is not identically distributed...the sales are heavily concentrated towards the end of the year.  Nor do I understand the two cases.  Are we to assume that, in the first case, the dealer's inventory is $12$ cars  on August $1$ or is the starting number also a random variable? And do you mean "at least $6$" or "exactly $6$"?   And I don't understand what variable you think is Poisson here.

Comment: @lulu: Maybe it implies binomial for any specified month (with success rate $1/2$ for January through August and $7/10$ for September through December). However, that doesn't yield an answer under $0.12$ either, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BrianTung  The problem is kind of a mess. Maybe we are meant to guess that it means $50\%$ over the entire $8$ months?  Though that seems to lead to very small results.  But, there are just too many points to guess at.

Comment: Binomial no Poisson - numbers too small.

Comment: @herbsteinberg the answer will be 22% when binomial is used, which is none of the choices

Comment: The problem statement must be incorrect.

Comment: list choices - clue to question.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Just added the choices

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the number of car trades in a given month is modeled by a binomial random variable with parameter $n$ representing the available inventory at the beginning of the month, and $p$ representing the probability of selling a given car in that inventory in that month.  So the sale of a car in the inventory is modeled as an independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trial with probability of sale $p$.

The probability that exactly $X = 6$ out of $n = 12$ cars are sold in August when the probability of an individual sale is $p = 0.5$, is $$s_1 = \Pr[X = 6 \mid n = 12, p = 0.5] = \binom{12}{6}(0.5)^{6}(1 - 0.5)^{12-6} \approx 0.225586.$$

Similarly, the probability that exactly $X = 2$ out of $n = 10$ cars are sold in September when the probability of an individual sale is $p = 0.7$, is $$s_2 = \Pr[X = 2 \mid n = 10, p = 0.7] = \binom{10}{2}(0.7)^2(1 - 0.7)^{10-2} \approx 0.0014467.$$

Therefore the probability that either of these two events occurs is $$1 - (1-s_1)(1-s_2) \approx 0.226706.$$

However, if instead the question asked for $2$ out of $10$ cars sold in August and $6$ out of $12$ cars sold in September, then we would have $$s_1 \approx 0.0792479, \\ s_2 \approx 0.0439453,$$ and the desired probability is $0.119711$, which when rounded is $12\%$.  Check the wording of the question and consider whether it might have been posed incorrectly.

Comment: Excellent guess, that might be what happened!